# C# generically set attribute

Tags: c#, class, reflection

I have a C# class that looks like this:

```
public class Model 
{ 
  public string title;
  public string name;
  ...
}
```

Somewhere I have a variable with the attribute I need to set `"title"` for example.
My C# is rather rusty but basically what I want to do is:

```
var attrToBeSet = "title";
var model = new Model();
model[attrToBeSet] = "someValue";
```

Obviously that is psuedocode but ... Is this even possible with C#?

Comment: You mean something like HashTable or HashMaps ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; reflection, in this case of a field (but a property would be better):

```
var attrToBeSet = "title";
var field = model.GetType().GetField(attrToBeSet);
field.SetValue(model, "someValue");
```

Note that this is much slower than regular code. If you are doing lots of this, there are ways to make reflection faster via meta-programming, perhaps baking things into an `Action<Model,object>` or similar via `DynamicMethod` - but that only matters if doing it lots.

Note that this should really be a property (you should avoid exposing fields directly):

```
public string Title {get;set;}
```

then:

```
var attrToBeSet = "Title";
var prop = model.GetType().GetProperty(attrToBeSet);
prop.SetValue(model, "someValue", null);
```

Comment: Holy !@#$% you answer very fast

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob sorry, I'll try to be slower in future... ;p (note: I tend to write the *main part* of an answer, and then edit it to improve it a bit... I do not, however, post a 1-line answer just to "reserve a place")

Comment: So fast I cant even accept as the right answer. :) Thanks @MarcGravell

Comment: [This method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2824409/2441808) (also your answer) is cool too.

Comment: @emodendroket yeah, that's a more hardcore way of doing it; I would tend to use FastMember or HyperDescriptor (also both mine) before using `Expression`, though

Comment: But expressions give you some member of type-safety/Intellisense/etc., so it can be useful, depending on what you're doing.  I found that a useful trick anyway.